# Global temporary table scope behaves differently inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, scope, temp-tables, linked-server

The following code executes successfully, unless I add `create procedure dbo.proc_name ... as` to it:

```
use db_name
go

declare @sp_date date;
select @sp_date = getdate();

if object_id('tempdb..##global_tmp_tbl') is not null drop table ##global_tmp_tbl;

begin transaction

  set xact_abort on

  declare @query varchar(250), @exec_stmnt varchar(500);
  set @query = 'exec remote_db.dbo.remote_sp'  + ' ''''' + cast(@sp_date as varchar(10)) + ''''' ';
  set @query = '''' + @query + '''';

  set @exec_stmnt = 'select * into ##global_tmp_tbl from openquery(LS_RMT,' +  @query + ')';

  exec (@exec_stmnt);

commit transaction
go

if object_id('tempdb..#local_tmp_tbl') is not null drop table #local_tmp_tbl;
select * into #local_tmp_tbl from ##global_tmp_tbl;
```

Here `LS_RMT` is a linked server, and `remote_sp` is a stored procedure on the database `remote_db` on that linked server.

When I try to put this code into a stored procedure, SQL Server complains that `##global_tmp_tbl` is an invalid name when trying to read from it after executing the stored procedure on the linked server which loads it.

I'm guessing that the scope of the global temporary table changes once within the context of a stored procedure, but I can't find any documentation on why that might be the case so I'm not sure.

Is this a scope issue, or is it actually possible to use the global temporary table within a stored procedure after it has been created inside a transaction that loads it from an openquery statement and I am just doing it wrong?

Comment: Global temp tables should be avoided almost always. Concurrency is a major problem with global temp tables.

Comment: Show the code that produces the error as well as the complete error message (all of it). GO divides your script into batches so it is not obvious how you choose to define your procedure and then execute it. Perhaps the better question is why you use temp tables in this fashion and why you choose to **NOT** let the procedure simply return the desired resultset and allow the consumer decide what to do with it. Seems to me you try to hard to reuse an inappropriate code pattern. And equally concerning is a procedure name that varies by date.

Comment: @SMor: this is only a relevant snippet of what the sp is doing. The results extracted from the sp on the linked server are stored in a temp table so that further processing can be done before storing the final results in a permanent table. The procedure name does not vary by date (and indeed is not even present); rather, the sp has a date parameter which can be specified - quite standard. Not sure what code pattern is "inappropriate" but it is generally advisable to assume that posted code represents a MWE and not infer what the process it fits within might be trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not entirely sure why the code above works when outside the context of a stored procedure, I did determine that embedding all references to the global temporary table within the committed transaction allowed the stored procedure to work. So something like the following:

```
use db_name
go

create procedure dbo.proc_name
@sp_date date = NULL

as
if isnull(@sp_date,'') = ''
begin
  select @sp_date = getdate();
end


if object_id('tempdb..##global_tmp_tbl') is not null drop table ##global_tmp_tbl;

begin transaction

  set xact_abort on

  declare @query varchar(250), @exec_stmnt varchar(500);
  set @query = 'exec remote_db.dbo.remote_sp'  + ' ''''' + cast(@sp_date as varchar(10)) + ''''' ';
  set @query = '''' + @query + '''';

  set @exec_stmnt = 'select * into ##global_tmp_tbl from openquery(LS_RMT,' +  @query + ')';

  exec (@exec_stmnt);

if object_id('tempdb..#local_tmp_tbl') is not null drop table #local_tmp_tbl;
select * into #local_tmp_tbl from ##global_tmp_tbl;

commit transaction
go
```